# PHP preg_match function get phone number from string

Tags: php, preg-match, str-replace

Here is my PHP code. I'm needing a regular expression to get my desired output.

```
$str = 'abc:123,phoneNumber:631 741-4498, fdsfdsf, hgjhtg,juiy';
```

**Expected Output:** `631741-4498`

```
$str = 'abc:123,phoneNumber:+123 423, fdsfdsf, hgjhtg,juiy';
```

**Expected Output:** +123 423

```
$str = 'abc:123,phoneNumber:+(123) 423-727, fdsfdsf, hgjhtg,juiy';
```

**Expected Output:** +(123) 423-727

Here's what I've tried

```
$str = 'abc:123,phoneNumber:631 741-4498, fdsfdsf, hgjhtg,juiy';
$str = str_replace(" ","",$str);
preg_match('/phoneNumber:\s*(.*)/', $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regular expression to `/(\d+ \d+\-\d+)/`

```
<?php

$str = 'abc:123,phoneNumber:631 741-4498, fdsfdsf, hgjhtg,juiy';
preg_match('/(\d+ \d+\-\d+)/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

#### [Live preview](https://eval.in/186549)

### Edit

Change your regular expression to `/phoneNumber:[a-zA-Z0-9\ \+\-(\(\))]+/`

```
<?php

$str = 'abc:123,phoneNumber:631 741-4498, fdsfdsf, hgjhtg,juiy';
preg_match('/phoneNumber:[a-zA-Z0-9\ \+\-(\(\))]+/', $str, $matches);

print_r( str_replace("phoneNumber:", "", $matches[0]) );
```

#### [Live preview](https://eval.in/186560)

#### [Live preview - all outputs](https://eval.in/186568)

Comment: Hello I want string between phoneNumber: and first comma. Middle string is change every time. It may +1234 or any other

Comment: Please edit your question and provide all possible character sets of the string.

Comment: Can you edit question properly. so any one wants it can get easily.